# Can't connect to postgreSQL database through php pdo driver

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I've decided to switch from MySQL to PostgreSQL recently, mostly just to learn a new DB.  It's been pretty painful, but I think I'm close.

I'm using php and PDO, my PDO driver has been successfully install and configured.

Opening my site, I get the error:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I'm using the following connection calls (I've tried a few variations of calling user/pw in the $dsn variable, and in separate $user/$pass variables, and including port=5432):

```
$dsn  = 'pgsql:dbname=db1;host=localhost;user=postgres;password=pass';
$db = new PDO($dsn);
```

Also, I'm able to log into my db from the command line:

```
$ su postgres
```

(pass)

```
$ psql db1
```

output:

> could not change directory to "/home/ec2-user" psql (8.4.9) Type
>   "help" for help.
>
> db1=#

Any ideas?  I'd love to provide more info if needed.

Comment: Is your pg_hba.conf file all right? It's a known source of pain at the beginning w/ PostgreSQL...

Comment: @maraspin: I _just_ tried messing with that before refreshing this page.  It worked.  I had to switch some 'ident' values to 'trust'.  Could you add that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Sure. Answer added. Tnx. :-) PS Watch outh, though. Your security might be put at risk with settings which are too loose. Once you've identified that your problem resides there, I suggest you to take another glance at the pg_hba.conf documentation and act accordingly. You'll see... it's something you'll need w/ PostgreSQL anyways ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your pg_hba.conf file all right? It's a known source of pain at the beginning w/ PostgreSQL. And, the situation you mention, is a good candidate for such kind of a problem. :-)

Comment: I had to change the values from `ident` to `trust` for my local and IPv4 records.  Finally, I have a fully working LAPP(5.4) server going.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad you've found the source for your problem. Now that you know exactly where to put your hands on, I suggest you to take a peek at the PostgreSQL documentation, so to properly configure the pg_hba.conf file. Can be important for your security.